# NameError: name 'sesssion_token' is not defined

Tags: python, flask

soy nuevo en el mundo de la programacion, y practicando con los token de session en flask, me da el error del titulo y despues de revisarlo no entiendo porque me dice que no esta definido el token de sesion cuando lo defino justo antes:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        data = {}
        session_token = request.cookies.get("session_token")                        #guardamos el valor de la cookie session token en la variable session_token

        if sesssion_token:
            user = db.query(User).filter_by(session_token=session_token).first()  #si tenemos una session token, miramos y comparamos en la base de datos
        else:                                                                       #si no creamos una instancia user vacia
            user = None

        data.update({'user': user})
        return render_template("index.html", data=data)
```

Comment: Hola Jesús, es un typo, es `if session_token:` no `if sesssion_token:`, te sobra una `s`.

Comment: madre mia..... jajajaja muchas gracias, llevo una hora dandole vueltas